# Ionic 3 get text from select option

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I have something like this

```
<ion-item formGroupName="Dealer">
                <ion-label color="primary" stacked>{{"Select dealer" | translate }}:</ion-label>
                <ion-select formControlName="Value" (ionChange)="getDealerName($event)">
                  <ion-option *ngFor="let dealer of dealerslist.Items" value="{{dealer.Value}}">{{dealer.Name}}</ion-option>
                </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

What i need is

```
public getDealerName(){
alert(dealer.Name);
}
```

I know in event i get value, but i need to get name of selected option?
I made it very simple that you can understand, again i dont need value i need text that is displayed in option

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows,

```
 <ion-select  (ionChange)="getDealerName()" [(ngModel)]="getSelectedValue">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let some of someItems" value="{{some.name}}"> {{some.value}} </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

and in component,

```
  getDealerName(){
     console.log(this.getSelectedValue);
     let term = this.someItems.filter(person => person.name ==this.getSelectedValue );
     alert('id is '+this.getSelectedValue);
     alert('value is '+term[0].value);
      console.log(event);

  }
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nnh9hw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

without two-way data-binding:

```
 <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let i of datalist">{{i}}</option>
 </select>

  onChange(datalistValue) {
   console.info(datalistValue);
 }
```

For two-way data-binding, separate the event and property bindings:

```
 <select [ngModel]="modalvalue" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
<option [value]="i" *ngFor="let i of datalist">{{i}}</option>
 </select>
export class Myapp{
 devices = 'one two three'.split(' ');
 modalvalue= 'two';
  onChange(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
  this.modalvalue= newValue;
   // ... do other stuff here ...
}
```